# return to launching activity when third party app closes

Tags: android, android-intent

I am launching some MP4 videos from within my application using the following INTENT (in activity B):

```
if (v == image5) {
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + "/.intro/Resources/Res5.mp4");
    if (file.exists()) {
        Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(path, "video/mp4");
        //intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        try {
            startActivity(intent);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.zoom_enter,
                    R.anim.zoom_exit);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {

        }
    }
}
```

When the video completes I would like android to return to the activity that launched the intent (Activity B), but it doesnt, instead it shows the launcher activity for my app (Activity A).  I have tried `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` but this made no difference.

EDIT: Full Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.my.app.trainer"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal"
    android:versionCode="14"
    android:versionName="1.1" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_splash_screen"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
        <!-- this is activity A -->
            android:name=".Main"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <!-- <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> -->
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Main3"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main3"
            android:parentActivityName=".Main"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.my.app.trainer.Main" />
        </activity>
       <activity
            android:name=".CNAChooser"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_cnachooser"
            android:parentActivityName=".Main3" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.my.app.trainer.Main3" />
        </activity>
        <activity
        <!-- this is activity B -->
            android:name=".CNARes"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_cnares"
            android:parentActivityName=".CNAChooser" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.my.app.trainer.CNAChooser" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

EDIT2:  I didnt have onResume() initially, but adding an onResume() has not changed the behavior.

How do I set the launching activity INTENT to ensure that when the video completes Activity B is shown?

EDIT3: Clear description - when I select the imagebutton for the video to play (with defaults reset for which video application to use) then Activity A displays behind the dialog asking which app to play the video with.

Question 2: Why does the intent listed above launch activity A?

I have tried removing and re-installing the app, but the behavior is the same.

Edit: checked the developer options, "Don't keep activities" is not enabled.

EDIT4:  I have checked the APK on 2 different android tablets and my S4 and the behavior is the same on all devices.  I also tried with a full clean and refresh from Eclipse.

EDIT5:  I have tried removing the animation and also tried FLAG_ACTIVITY_PREVIOUS_IS_TOP and still get the same behavior.  I have also tried changing the intent to launch a PDF file using code that I know works from my Activity A (main) class file.  I am really confused what is going on here.

Thanks;

Andy

Comment: Use startActivityForResult.

Comment: Is that not used to pass information (ints etc) between activities?

Comment: By default navigating back from third party app to current app call   `onResume` method of the activity that started the intent . Either you are setting some wrong flag or some wrong setting in the manifest.

Comment: Thanks.  I dont have an onResume method for the launching activity so that could be the problem.

Comment: onResume is always there, by default. even if you don't override it.

Comment: Edited my question above if that helps understand what I have done wrong

Comment: are you using a device where, in the developer options, is "Don't keep activities" enabled?

Comment: post manifest for activity A. In fact, post your whole manifest.

Comment: Make sure that you aren't calling `finish()` in Activity B after (or before) you call `startActivity()` to launch the video viewer.

Comment: Manifest added. I don't call finish () at all, the only call I make for the intent is in the code above.

Comment: Anyone have any thoughts what is going on with this issue? I am going crazy trying to work it out.

Comment: I'm assuming everyone is as stumped as me why this is happening then? Anyone have a clue at all that could set me off on the right path?